# Wordpress display specific taxonomy term on custom taxonomy template page

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm beyond my capabilities in figuring this problem out.

**What I need to accomplish:**
On [this page](http://citymiamihomes.com/new-developments/doral/) I need to display the results of only the items labeled with the term "Doral" under my custom taxonomy of "New Developments" which is a part of the custom post type "Listings".

Currently the page is displaying all items regardless of the term or taxonomy for the custom post type "Listing".

**What I currently have:**
My custom taxonomy creation code

```
add_action('init', 'property_new_dev_taxonomies');
function property_new_dev_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy('new-developments',
        'listing',
        array (
        'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'New Developments',
                'singluar_name' => 'New Developments',
                'search_items' => 'Search New Developments',
                'popular_items' => 'Popular New Developments',
                'all_items' => 'All New Developments',
                'parent_item' => 'Parent New Development',
                'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent New Development:',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit New Development',
                'update_item' => 'Update New Development',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Development',
                'new_item_name' => 'New Developments',
        ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_tagcloud' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'new-developments'),
                'query_var' => 'new-developments',
                'public'=>true)
        );
}
```

**My custom taxonomy template (taxonomy-new-developments.php)**

```
<?php 

/*
    Template Name: Taxonomy New Developments
*/ 

?>


<?php get_header() ?>


<div id="columnswrapper" class="columns-1">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="norightsidebar">
        <div class="inner">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php $term = $wp_query->queried_object; echo '<h2>'.$term->name.'</h2>'; ?>

    <?php $term = new WP_Query('post_type=listing', 'taxonomy=new-developments', 'field=slug',  'terms=doral'); ?>

    <?php if ($term->have_posts()) : while ($term->have_posts()) : $term->the_post(); ?>
    <?php include 'includes/variables.php' ?>


    <div class="searchresult">

        <?php 
        $arr_sliderimages = get_gallery_images();   
        //$firstimage = $arr_sliderimages[0];
        //$arr_sliderimages = parse_url($firstimage);
        $resized = aq_resize($arr_sliderimages[0], 250, 185, true);
        ?>  

        <div class="resultimage">


            <?php include 'includes/bannerssmall.php'; ?>


            <?php if ($mlslisting == "Yes" && $mlsnumber) { ?>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/idx/mls-<?php echo $mlsnumber ?>-"><img width="250" height="185" alt="Image for <?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $resized ?>" /></a>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="250" height="185" alt="Image for <?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $resized ?>" /></a>
            <?php } ?>  


        </div>

        <div class="resultdetails">
            <div class="primary-data">
                <div class="address">

                <?php if ($mlslisting == "Yes" && $mlsnumber) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/idx/mls-<?php echo $mlsnumber ?>-"><?php the_title() ?>, <?php echo $citystatezip ?></a>
                 <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?>, <?php echo $citystatezip ?></a>
            <?php } ?>



                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <?php include 'includes/price.php'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="secondary-data">
                <?php if ($beds) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo $beds ?> <?php echo get_option('wp_bedrooms_text'); ?>, <?php echo $baths; ?> <?php echo get_option('wp_bathrooms_text'); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($homesize) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo get_option('wp_homesize_text') ?>: <?php echo $homesize ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($lotsize) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo get_option('wp_lotsize_text') ?>: <?php echo $lotsize ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($year) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo get_option('wp_yearbuilt_text') ?>: <?php echo $year ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>  

            <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_option('wp_read_more_text') ?></a>


        </div><!-- end resultdetails -->
    </div><!-- end searchresult -->

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><strong>There are no items to display.  Make sure you add 1 or more posts using the "Listings" category.  Also, in Theme Options, make sure the slideshow is using the "Listings" category.</strong></p>

        <?php endif; 
        wp_reset_query(); ?> 

    </div><!-- end inner -->
    </div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end columnswrapper -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have been trying to get the myself for far too long and desperately need some help to get this working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

=========================================
**EDIT: Tried this based on comments but it's still not working -**

```
<?php 

/*
    Template Name: Taxonomy New Developments
*/ 

?>


<?php get_header() ?>


<div id="columnswrapper" class="columns-1">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="norightsidebar">
        <div class="inner">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php $term = $wp_query->queried_object; echo '<h2>'.$term->name.'</h2>'; ?>

    <?php $term = new WP_Query('post_type=listing', 'taxonomy=new-developments', 'field=slug',  'terms=doral'); ?>

    <?php if ($term->have_posts()) :
    $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'Listing',
                'new-developments' => $term->slug
            );
     query_posts($args);
     while ($term->have_posts()) : $term->the_post(); ?>
    <?php include 'includes/variables.php' ?>


    <div class="searchresult">

        <?php 
        $arr_sliderimages = get_gallery_images();   
        //$firstimage = $arr_sliderimages[0];
        //$arr_sliderimages = parse_url($firstimage);
        $resized = aq_resize($arr_sliderimages[0], 250, 185, true);
        ?>  

        <div class="resultimage">


            <?php include 'includes/bannerssmall.php'; ?>


            <?php if ($mlslisting == "Yes" && $mlsnumber) { ?>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/idx/mls-<?php echo $mlsnumber ?>-"><img width="250" height="185" alt="Image for <?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $resized ?>" /></a>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="250" height="185" alt="Image for <?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $resized ?>" /></a>
            <?php } ?>  


        </div>

        <div class="resultdetails">
            <div class="primary-data">
                <div class="address">

                <?php if ($mlslisting == "Yes" && $mlsnumber) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/idx/mls-<?php echo $mlsnumber ?>-"><?php the_title() ?>, <?php echo $citystatezip ?></a>
                 <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?>, <?php echo $citystatezip ?></a>
            <?php } ?>



                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <?php include 'includes/price.php'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="secondary-data">
                <?php if ($beds) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo $beds ?> <?php echo get_option('wp_bedrooms_text'); ?>, <?php echo $baths; ?> <?php echo get_option('wp_bathrooms_text'); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($homesize) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo get_option('wp_homesize_text') ?>: <?php echo $homesize ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($lotsize) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo get_option('wp_lotsize_text') ?>: <?php echo $lotsize ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($year) { ?>
                    <div><?php echo get_option('wp_yearbuilt_text') ?>: <?php echo $year ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>  

            <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_option('wp_read_more_text') ?></a>


        </div><!-- end resultdetails -->
    </div><!-- end searchresult -->

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><strong>There are no items to display.  Make sure you add 1 or more posts using the "Listings" category.  Also, in Theme Options, make sure the slideshow is using the "Listings" category.</strong></p>

        <?php endif; 
        wp_reset_query(); ?> 

    </div><!-- end inner -->
    </div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end columnswrapper -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: the answer below should work for you

Comment: @boom_Shiva Just tried it and it didn't work, did I get something wrong? See my edit above for my code update.

Comment: $term->slug should be replaced by "Doral"

Comment: @boom_Shiva that doesn't really help in keeping these dynamic, I would have to create a template for each and every term each time the client makes a new term. Not a good solution for long-term maintenance, is there no way to dynamically fill the term field based on the url of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass below code before while loop of have_posts

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'Listing',
                'new-developments' => $term->slug
            );
     query_posts($args);
      if (have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : 
              the_post();
 endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I updated my code according to your comment as follows but with no change, did I do it in the wrong place?

`<?php if ($term->have_posts()) :
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'Listing',
'new-developments' => $term->slug
);
query_posts($args);
while ($term->have_posts()) : $term->the_post(); ?>`

Comment: yes you need to write like updated code in above and have you replace  $term->slug to your term's slug?

Comment: Is there no way of having a dynamic slug based on the url of the page? These terms will be continually updated and in order to maintain this method I would have to create a new template for each term for it to display. Not a good solution for my client as they have no way of creating their own templates.

Comment: Also, I did try the code changing the $term->doral and no change occurred I'm still getting all the results for the post_type 'Listing'

Comment: you just need to pass term name like 'new-developments' => 'Doral'

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use get_query_var http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var to get the current category under new_development and then you can query the post for that category.

```
  $current_cat = get_query_var('new-developments');
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Listing',
    'new-developments' => $current_cat
  );
 query_posts($args);
 if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : 
          the_post();
    endwhile;
 endif;
```

Comment: this did not change anything. What I'm finding out is that this line of code that I have: `    <?php $term = new WP_Query('post_type=listing', 'taxonomy=new-developments', 'field=slug'); ?>
` is controlling everything. If I remove it I get no results on the page regardless of what other code I may place after it so logic tells me this is what needs to be modified, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Comment: I just updated the code, $term->have_posts() replaced by have_posts only as I'm using query posts, and can you echo and check if you are getting anything in $current_cat